# Grafana IAC - Dashboard Creation Error - A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access specifying the resource name

Tags: terraform, grafana, crossplane

I'm using Crossplane Grafana provider to create Grafana Dashboards through IAC on my Grafana Cloud instance. I created the Dashboard through the UI, exported the JSON and tried to feed it into the [Grafana Dashboard Resource](https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/grafana/provider-grafana/v0.6.0/resources/oss.grafana.crossplane.io/Dashboard/v1alpha1#doc:spec-forProvider-configJson).

Despite I didn't changed anything, I receive the following error message on Kubernetes:

```
Invalid reference: A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name
```

This message is repeated several times each retry. No more information.

Couldn't find the `.lock` file on the Crossplane Grafana Provider Resource through `kubectl exec` to check if there was any other meaningful message...

I figured out this message is actually a Terraform message, as Crossplane uses Upbound/upjet as a translation layer to Terraform. Not a very helpful one though...

Comment: Well, I don's see how we can help without seeing the code you are using. But to me it seems terraform is seeing the dashboards as if they were using references to resources, which is not what you are trying to do, so you probably need to fix the JSON.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment, I posted only to document what I found for future reference if somebody else fall on this. I have solved the issue already. Didn't posted the JSON with Grafana Dashboards as they are very long, this one has 3K lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a bit, I figured out that the Terraform error message comes from it trying to interpolate a variable, such as `${resource.field}`.

With this information, looking the 3K line Json I found out that Datasource Variables from Grafana can be pointed at with the following notation: `${env}` or `$env`. When the first happens, it is triggering the Terraform API to force the interpolation.

To bypass that, Terraform accepts `$${env}`, which will be interpolated as `${env}`, finally being accepted by the Grafana API.

So, quick fix, add a second `$`.